# URL mapping for array of objects

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I have problem with passing array of complex objects. Object it is longitude, latitude, start and end time. All of object properties is double type. So I need something like that if write it in JSON format: 
`[{"longitude" : 231, "latitude" : 213, "start_time" : 2134 , "end time" : 2347},{"longitude" : 647, "latitude" : 435, "start_time" : 34 , "end time" : 788},...]` 
What I should write in @PathVariable and @RequestMapping(value = ) or @RequestParam for pass it

Comment: Why are you passing these as path variables instead of request parameters?

Comment: @chrylis does not matter, I also don't know how to pass as request parameter

Comment: first create a class MyObject that binds to the json array items; then use `@RequestBody List<MyObject> objects` as the controller method parameter

Comment: @guido It's a get method